# edit specific id from url in Angular

Tags: angularjs

how can i edit inputs from this ID :

[image]

i added `<a href="#/edit?data={{data.ID}}">Edit</a>` in home template and pass the id to edit.html .

how can i edit input from this ID ?

**edit.html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="name" ng-model="subject"/>

    <input type="button" name="edit" ng-click="edit(data.ID)" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Define "edit input".

Comment: have you tried `$location.search('key', value)`?

Comment: Not really clear on your issue, but it sounds like you need to at least make the `href` attribute into an `ng-href`: `<a ng-href="#/edit?data={{data.ID}}">Edit</a>`

Comment: sry , but how can i use this id ? when i write {{data.id}} in edit view nothing happend

Comment: no @hgoebl,is that what i want ?

Comment: @JBNizet as i wrote , i define that but i don't have access id in my edit template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to refer to `data.ID` in the view and you have `?data=23` in your url then you should use `$location` to define it in the controller like so:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.data.ID = $location.search().data
})
```

and now it would be available to your view as `data.ID`